# How can I integrate PhpBB with moodle

Tags: module, phpbb, moodle, integrate

I'm using moodle but I need a better forum, so I was thinking that PHPbb was a good idea, then I need to integrate the phpbb forum into moodle. Is it possible? Can anybody help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The integration of two complex [Moodle and PHPbb] systems with different designs always
>   brings problems. We tried it several times before and it never ended
>   well
>
> The reasons to close this issue are similar as in the Mediawiki bug -
>   different design and coding style, incompatible user data storage,
>   missing grading, etc.
>
> Closing as will not fix, sorry.

On http://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-7082